# Calling django query sets when user needs them

Tags: django

I have been going back and forward with ideas doing this and none of them has worked so I'm gonna ask for ideas. I have model called "List" that users can create for example "Sleep" Then they have input where they select one of their lists and can add value for example 8. Good sleep! After that user sees a graph based on the data that he/(she has entered. All that is already working but I cannot seem to find a way to get data organized.

I'm trying to do it so list "sleep" calls all it's values to the graph and then other list lets say "money" shows all its money values. I am using chart.js to draw the graphs and I dont care if they are all at the same time on the screen or if one by one but for somereason I cannot call these querysets properly. Only way it works is if I use .all() and that wont work since I have multiple users.

**Models:**

```
class List(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='lists')

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Meta:
    unique_together = ['name', 'user']


class DataItem(models.Model):
    data = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    list = models.ForeignKey(List, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='data_items')r code here
```

**Views**

```
@login_required
    def app(request):
    form = list_form
    form2 = data_form

    user = request.user.pk
    user_lists = List.objects.filter(user=user)

    context = {'user_lists': user_lists, 'form': form, 'form2': form2}

return render(request, 'MyApp/app.html', context)

@require_POST
     def addItem(request):
     form = list_form(request.POST)

     if form.is_valid():
     user = request.user
     new_list = List(name=request.POST['text'], user=user)
     new_list.save()

return redirect('/app/')

@require_POST
def addData(request):
    form = data_form(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
    new_data = DataItem(data=request.POST['data'],  list=List.objects.get(id=request.POST['selection'])) 
    new_data.save()

return redirect('/app/')
```

"addItem" adds an list (money and sleep)
"addData" adds an value to selected list

I have no glue where to start making what I descibed.. Should I filter the data sets in main view? make own view for it and call them with buttons?
Please be specific if you have some idea how to make that kind of function since i'm pretty new to django. Thanks :)

Comment: you said you tried to call “these querysets” and that didn’t work and you have to call “all()”. Where is that? What error do you get? Why are you showing us POST views to crate data if your question is about fetching data to show in a graph?

Comment: Try to reduce your question to a small specific problem, write [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it you want to get all lists that a User has created, and then create graphs for them. First of all, I recommend adding a `DateTimeField()` to the `DataItem` model. For example: `created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)`.

Then, in a view, you can get all of the data for a users list like this:

```
@login_required
def app(request):
    form = list_form
    form2 = data_form

    user = request.user.pk
    user_lists = List.objects.filter(user=user)

    list_data = {}
    for list in user_lists:
        list_data[list.name] = DataItem.objects.filter(list=list)

    context = {'user_lists': user_lists, 'form': form, 'form2': form2, 'list_data': list_data}

    return render(request, 'MyApp/app.html', context)
```

This will save all of the data you need in list data. If you took my advice at the beginning of the response, you could also sort it by `created` to get chronological. In the template, you can loop through this list. The key is the name of the list, and the value will be a queryset of the data entries.